# Finding the $n$ value of a summation relative to the value of the summation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I'm writing an algorithm that iterates over an array, so I know that each time it executes a function process(A, i,j) such that it can process f(t) elements of the array so the first pass t = 1, it processes $2^{t-1}+1 = 2^0+1 = 2$ elements.
I update i and j so that each pass processes new elements.

To find out how many times will f(t) be called, I need to find the final t.
To do that, I know that the sum of all elements processed is equal to or less than the length of the array,  which I'll call n.

The problem here is that I'm not sure of how to obtain this final t, let's call it x, so:

$\sum _{t=1}^x\:(2^{t-1}+1) = n $

I know that $\sum _{t=0}^x\:2^t = 2^{t+1}-1$

and  $\sum _{t=1}^x\:(2^{t-1}+1) = \sum _{t=1}^x\:2^{t-1} +  \sum _{t=1}^x\:1$

But I'm unsure if that information is helpful in my case or how I would apply that to obtain x. Any tips or sources for that would help.

Edited:

$\sum _{t=1}^x\:(2^{t-1}+1) = (2^{1-1} + 1) + (2^{2-1} + 1) +  ... +  (2^{x-1} + 1) = n $

So x should be a function of n

Comment: If each iteration uses 1 or 2 or ...or n, then $\sum _{t=1}^x\:2^{t-1}+1 <= n $. Not $"=n"$. Also, the L.H.S in the following should be some function of $x$ but the R.H.S is a function of $t$: "I know that $\sum _{t=0}^x\:2^t = 2^{t+1}-1$". Please check.

Comment: Just to be sure : could you post the very first terms after $(1,2, ???)$

Comment: You're missing parentheses around the summands on the left-hand sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem being to find $x$ such that
$$\sum_{t=1}^{x} (2^{t-1}+1)=2^x+x-1=n$$
in the real domain, it means that we look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=2^x+x-(n+1)$$
This has an explicit solution in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
$$x=(n+1)-\frac{1}{\log (2)}\,W\left(2^{n+1} \log (2)\right)$$ which has series representation (look at the linked page).

If you cannot use it, and I think that you do not need it, notice that since
$$f(x) > 2^x-(n+1)\qquad \implies \qquad x < \frac{\log (n+1)}{\log (2)}$$

So, using the above as an $x_0$, the first iterate of Newton method is
$$\color{blue}{x_1=\frac{(n+1) \log (n+1)}{(n+1) \log (2)+1}}$$

By Darboux theorem, we know that it is an overestimate of the solution but, in this specific case (almost speaking of integers)
i will be quite a small difference. In fact $\Delta=x_1-x$ goes through a maximum value of $0.086$ for $n=3.89$ and dcreases to $0^+$.

So, if I am not mistanken, the solution is
$$\large\color{red}{x=\left\lceil \frac{(n+1) \log (n+1)}{(n+1) \log   (2)+1}\right\rceil}$$

.